# LWC: wire apex to property with @api param value

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

Is there a way to get result from apex method if param is @api value (that comes from parent)?

like this:

```
@api trip; // comes from parent
@wire(getTickets, { recordId: '$trip.Id' }) tickets;
```

or how to pass this param?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a setter-getter for `tripId` and use it to extract the `@wire` configuration value.

Here's what that looks like:

```
tripId; // value to use with @wire

_trip; // private var used with getter-setter
@api 
set trip(value) {
    this._trip = value;
    this.tripId = value.Id; // extract the value 
}
get trip() { return this._trip; }

@wire(getTickets, { recordId: '$tripId' }) tickets;
```

This approach with a getter-setter is preferred over other solutions (eg a getter only on tripId) because it'll keep this.tripId up to date whenever this.trip is changed.

Comment: Cool !! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it works like that:

```
    @api trip;
    @track tripId;
    @wire(getTickets, { recordId: '$tripId' }) tickets;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.tripId = this.trip.Id;
    }
```

Comment: This approach is not good because it does a one-time copy of the value of `this.tripId`. `tripId` is `@api` so the parent component may change the value at any time.

Comment: so do i need pass 2 params? how to pass only 'trip' record and pass trip.Id to apex method?